# Regex: Split string on number/string?

Tags: php, regex, string, split, numbers

Consider the following:

```
700italic
regular
300bold
300bold900
```

All of those are different examples, only one of the rows will be executed per time.

Expected outcome:

```
// 700italic
array(
    0 => 700
    1 => itailc
)

// regular
array(
    0 => regular
)

// 300bold
array(
    0 => 300
    1 => bold
)

// 300bold900
array(
    0 => 300
    1 => bold
    2 => 900
)
```

I made the following:

```
(\d*)(\w*)
```

But it's not enough. It kinda works when i only have two "parts" (number|string or string|number) but if i add a third "segment" to it i wont work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarcB won't work. `\w` will consume the digits, too

Comment: Nope since `\w` matches digits as well. It'd have to be `(\d*)(\w*?)(\d*)`

Comment: Also nice one: [`preg_split('/(?:\d++|\D++)\B\K/', $str)`](https://eval.in/848305)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead. Then you can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that match a position between a word an a letter:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i', $input);
```

Note that `\w` matches digits (and underscores), too, in addition to letters.

The alternative (using a matching function) is to use `preg_match_all` and match only digits **or** letters for every match:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+|[a-z]+/i', $input, $result);
```

Instead of captures you will now get a single match for every of the desired elements in the resulting array. But you only want the array in the end, so you don't really care where they come from.

Answer (score 1):

Could use the [`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) flag.

Example:

```
<?php

$key= "group123425";
$pattern = "/(\d+)/";

$array = preg_split($pattern, $key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);

?>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908327/how-to-explode-a-string-by-any-integer-regex) post as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
preg_split(
    '((\d+|\D+))', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
)
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/4550)

Or [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
preg_match_all('(\d+|\D+)', $test, $matches) && $matches = $matches[0];
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/4559)

Answer (score 0):

You should match it instead of splitting it..

Still you can split it using

```
(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)
```

Comment: +1 for writing exactly the same solution at pretty much exactly the same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
(\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)
```

Or you can use `preg_match_all` with a pattern like this:

```
'/(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+)/'
```

Then you can match an arbitrary number of segments, each consisting of only letters or only digits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
(\d*)(bold|italic|regular)(\d*)
```

or

```
(\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)
```