# PHP string split into 2

Tags: php, string, split

I've got string like this

```
$str = "cl2"

$str2 = "L1"
```

What i'm trying to get is the LAST NUMERIC NUMER and whatever is before the numeric number

Result I want is

```
$result[0] = "cl"
$result[1] = "2"

$result[0] = "L"
$result[1] = "1"
```

I've been looking at explode() and str_split() php functions to use but cant seem to find a way to only get the last digit, then everything else before it  thanks

Comment: What you need is preg_split() http://php.net/preg-split

Comment: The string inputs always end with numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP split string into integer element and string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string. It answers what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to explode a string by any integer? Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908327/how-to-explode-a-string-by-any-integer-regex)

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.You can split whatever is before the numeric number

```
<?php
$str = "cl2";
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i', $str);
?>
```

Another way from [@Marcus's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908327/how-to-explode-a-string-by-any-integer-regex) answer

```
<?php
$str = "cl2";   
$result = preg_split("/(\d+)/", $str , -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);    
?>
```

Then result is :

```
$result[0] = "cl"
$result[1] = "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
I ended up using substr to solve my problem

```
$str = "CL2"
$result[0] = substr($str, 0, -1); // returns "CL"
$result[1] = substr($str, -1); // returns "2"
```

Comment: A robust program would not only get the results you think you want, but verify that the right types of data have been acquired.